# Get the file size along with file name

Tags: unix

Have a request to find files available in a multiple directory along with the size of file.

Need output in the below format.

```
File Name File Size
abc 1024 bytes
xyz 2048 bytes
```

This is to find all the files available in different directories in unix box and also to find the size of each file.

`$chk_dir/$f*` is the path/filename ( this will be list of multiple filenames residing in different directory).

```
case "$chk_dir/$f*" in

    *.Z)      zcat $chk_dir/$f* | wc -c >> final.dat ;;

    *.gz)     gzip -cd $chk_dir/$f* | wc -c >> final.dat ;;

    *)        wc -c $chk_dir/$f* >> final.dat ;;

esac
```

Expected result:

```
File Name File Size

abc       1024 bytes
xyz       2048 bytes
```

Actual Result:

```
user@ /path # zcat abc.csv.Z | wc -c
   94310 

user@ /path # gzip -cd abc.new.gz | wc -c
 8980094

user@ /path # wc -c abc
    3645 abc
```

Comment: What is your current attempt at resolving this and where are you getting struck

Comment: Thanks for responding Nitin ,I am not able to get the file name along with the size.user@ /path # zcat abc.csv.Z | wc -c 94310

user@ /path # gzip -cd abc.new.gz | wc -c 8980094

user@ /path # wc -c abc 3645 abc . What i am expecting is as mentioned below user@ /path # zcat abc.csv.Z | wc -c 94310 abc.csv

user@ /path # gzip -cd abc.new.gz | wc -c 8980094 abc.new

user@ /path # wc -c abc  3645 abc